# Windows Live Messenger stops space bar working

Tags: windows-vista, windows-live-messenger

On Windows Vista, the included Windows Live Messenger frequently stops the space bar working after a long period (or is it after I put the computer into standby).

It is frustrating to have to exit Windows Live Messenger and re-start just so I can type spaces in conversations.

Anybody else have this problem?

Comment: Are you using any extensions, hotkey software or software that hooks into WLM?

Answer (score 0):

The modifier keys might affect the behavior of the space bar, try to play with them to see if it resolves.